# Calling system() or IPC::Run3 commands from perl don't seem to pass environment variable ($ENV{JAVA_HOME})

Tags: java, perl, nutch, env

I've been struggling with launching a java process from perl. The root of the problem is that the java process is missing the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable causing a `ClassNotFoundException`.

I started by using `IPC::Run3` because of its relatively elegant redirection of STDIN/STDOUT.

Assuming `IPC::Run3` would use `%ENV`, I tried adding `$ENV{JAVA_HOME}`.

When that didn't work I tried doing `system()`. That didn't work, so finally, I got it to work using `system("JAVA_HOME=/path/to/java && /path/to/java_program");`

My test program is below. Naturally I'd uncomment the proper block to test the appropriate invocation.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

use IPC::Run3;

use vars qw(%Config $nutch_stdout $nutch_stderr);

%Config = (
  'nutch_binary'       => q[/home/crawl/nutch/runtime/local/bin/nutch],
  'nutch_crawl_dir'    => q[/home/crawl/nutch-crawl/crawl/crawldb/current/part-00000],
  'nutch_seed_dir'     => q[/home/crawl/urls],
  'solr_url'           => q[http://localhost:8080/solr],
);

my @nutch_command = ("$Config{nutch_binary}",
                 "crawl $Config{nutch_seed_dir}",
                 "-solr $Config{solr_url}",
                 "-d    $Config{nutch_crawl_dir}",
                 "-threads 1",
                 "-depth 1");

$ENV{JAVA_HOME}       = '/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0';

while ((my $key,my $value) = each %ENV) {
    print "$key=$value\n";
}

print "Running @nutch_command\n";

# My original code. Next few lines are shown in first batch of output below.
#run3 \@nutch_command, undef, \$nutch_stdout, \$nutch_stderr;
#print "Output from Nutch:\n";
#print $nutch_stdout;
#print "Errors from Nutch:\n";
#print $nutch_stderr;

# Second try. The next line's output is the second batch of output.
#system(@nutch_command);

# Third try. Despite setting and displaying %ENV, this is the only thing I tried that worked
system("JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0 && @nutch_command");
```

Here's the output of running the run3:

```
    -bash-3.2$ ./test.pl 
    ... [snip] ...
    JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0
    ... [snip] ...
    Running /home/crawl/nutch/runtime/local/bin/nutch crawl /home/crawl/urls -solr http://localhost:8080/solr -d    /home/crawl/nutch-crawl/crawl/crawldb/current/part-00000 -threads 1 -depth 1
    Output from Nutch:
    Errors from Nutch:
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: crawl
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: crawl
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    Could not find the main class: crawl. Program will exit.
```

And the output of the first system() call:

```
    -bash-3.2$ ./test.pl
    ... [snip] ...
    JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0
    ... [snip] ...
    Running /home/crawl/nutch/runtime/local/bin/nutch crawl /home/crawl/urls -solr http://localhost:8080/solr -d    /home/crawl/nutch-crawl/crawl/crawldb/current/part-00000 -threads 1 -depth 1
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: crawl
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: crawl
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    Could not find the main class: crawl. Program will exit.
```

Finally, the third system call-- the only one that worked!-- with the environment variable set inline:

```
    -bash-3.2$ ./test.pl
    ... [snip] ...
    JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0
    ... [snip] ...
    Running /home/crawl/nutch/runtime/local/bin/nutch crawl /home/crawl/urls -solr http://localhost:8080/solr -d    /home/crawl/nutch-crawl/crawl/crawldb/current/part-00000 -threads 1 -depth 1
    crawl started in: crawl-20120216133832
    ... continue success stdout output
```

Finally to the question: Aside from having to set the environment in-line with the system() call, what's the appropriate way to pass an environment var to a IPC::Run3 or a system() call?

(Note: output of %ENV is truncated to only relevant lines... lines like PATH, SHELL, _, etc. not relevant to the question omitted)

In case it's relevant:

```
-bash-3.2$ uname -a
Linux hostname 2.6.18-238.el5xen #1 SMP Thu Jan 13 16:41:45 EST 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
-bash-3.2$ perl --version
This is perl, v5.8.8 built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi
```

Comment: Simply setting %ENV should be enough. What do you get from: `perl -e'die if $ENV{FOO_BAR}; $ENV{FOO_BAR} = "/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0"; system(q{echo --$FOO_BAR--});'`. ("This is perl, v5.8.9 built for i686-linux-thread-multi". Gonna install 5.8.8)

Comment: By the way, `system("JAVA_HOME=/path/to/java && /path/to/java_program");` can be simplified to `system("JAVA_HOME=/path/to/java /path/to/java_program");`

Comment: My simplified version also works with v5.8.8 built for i686-linux-thread-multi.

Comment: Hey ikegami, here's what I get: 
perl -e'die if $ENV{FOO_BAR}; $ENV{FOO_BAR} = "/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0"; system(q{echo --$FOO_BAR--});'
--/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0--

Comment: ok, I'm dumbfounded. What relevant difference could there be between that snippet and yours?! The code you posted is the code you ran, right? Specifically, the program you ran didn't create threads, right?

Comment: It didn't create threads (lightweight processes) it just (originally) did a IPC::Run3 call, essentially equivalent to a system() call.

The only thing that seems to inform system() of my desire to set the JAVA_HOME var is the system([env] && [cmd]) (or as you pointed out, system([foo=bar] [cmd]) syntax).

I'd really like to figure out why %ENV isn't getting passed to IPC::Run3 or system() without such explicit passing of vars.

Comment: Actually, you just showed that `%ENV` being passed to `system` without any "explicit passing of vars", so the key if finding the relevant difference between the two snippets.

Comment: Right. Doing so via perl -e passed it but not in my script.  So I think I may have figured it out, at least for the system() call. Specifically, putting the `system(@nutch_command);` into quotes seems to do the trick: `system("@nutch_command");`

Now the trick is to figure out how to make run3 work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The root of the problem is that the java process is missing the JAVA_HOME environment variable causing a ClassNotFoundException.

**REVISED**

That is not the root of the problem.  In fact, *Java itself* does not require JAVA_HOME to be set.

The immediate cause of the problem is one of the following:

- The wrapper is not setting the **classpath** correctly for the application that you are trying to execute.
- The wrapper using the wrong class name.  The class name "nutch" is unusual and suspicious - there's no package name.

It seems likely that the real root cause is that you are assembling the argument list incorrectly.  Each of those arguments with a space inside them should really be two arguments; i.e.

```
        my @nutch_command = ("$Config{nutch_binary}",
             "crawl", "$Config{nutch_seed_dir}",
             "-solr", "$Config{solr_url}",
             "-d", "$Config{nutch_crawl_dir}",
             "-threads", "1",
             "-depth", "1");
```

I suspect that this has confused the nutch wrapper script, and caused it to use the wrong classname (among other things).  When you pass the entire command as one string and let the shell parse it, the problem (naturally) goes away.

Comment: Thanks, Stephen, but the essence of what I was saying is true, that defining the JAVA_HOME enables nutch to run properly.

I've read that document, and am quite familiar with it. What I'm doing within perl isn't just writing a wrapper script, although my test code certainly looks like that's all I'm doing because I wanted to distill the problem-- why perl doesn't seem to be paying attention to the %ENV hash-- down to its essence.

I am doing a lot of prep work ahead of the nutch crawl, and have more work to do after the crawl that I choose to do with perl.

However, I will look into using -cp.

Comment: It does, because nutch is just a shell script, and contains bash code like: ``if [ "$JAVA_HOME" = "" ]; then
  echo "Error: JAVA_HOME is not set."
  exit 1
fi``

Comment: You nailed it... Thanks a ton!